# Бесконечная прокрутка в обе стороны FlatList - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

Я пытаюсь сделать Flatlist с бесконечной прокруткой в ​​обоих направлениях.

Уже есть небольшой набросок реализации (https://snack.expo.dev/@slam_ua/flatlist-loop), но я не могу понять как сделать несколько вещей:

1. Бесшовный список. Чтоб прокрутка не останавливалась и шла по кругу, когда список доходит до конца.
2. Бесконечная прокрутка вверх.
3. Центрирование начального элемента (00) по центру (из картинки с примером будет понятно о чем я).

Ниже пример результата, которого я хочу достичь:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/prateek3255/react-native-infinite-looping-scroll